# Completely Delete Xcode project and all references?

Tags: ios4, xcode4, project

Every time I try to delete my project, and create a new one under the previous name that i deleted, the icons and references are still there.  I can't seem to fully delete it then start again with the same name.  Any help is appreciated.

Using: Xcode 4

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Close the project then delete it with Finder. Open Xcode's Organizer window (Cmd-Shift-2) and click the Projects tab. Find and delete the project from that list. Close the organizer than try creating your project again.

Also, file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com - this shouldn't be necessary but I have seen it before (in 4.0 betas).

Answer (score 3):

A solution for Xcode 6:

(You can skip steps 2 and 4 if you just want Xcode to forget the project, but don't want to remove the actual project files.)

1. Go to Window ▸ Projects.
2. In the list on the left, secondary-click on the project you want to delete, and select "Reveal in Finder".
3. Go back to Xcode and secondary-click again on the project in the Projects sub-window, and this time select "Remove from Projects...". This will remove the project from Xcode, but won't delete the actual project files.
4. Go to the Finder window that opened in step  2 and move the project folder to trash.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to get rid of the unwanted projects when you control-select on Xcode in docks:

1) Follow Joshua's instructions above
2) Quit xCode
3) Control-click on "show recents"

Now only the projects you have left will show up.

Answer (score -2):

In Xcode 4.3, close the project, close Xcode, then use finder to delete the project folder.  Next time you launch Xcode the project should be gone.